# Floatingtable, always "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)"

Tags: warnings

What LaTeX is trying to do with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\begin{document}

\begin{floatingtable}[r]{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{tabular}}
\end{floatingtable}

This is MWE.

\end{document}
```

I got

`Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--10`

and message disappears if I add `\raggedright` after `\begin{document}`. It does not make any difference if I add more words to "This is MWE." -paragraph or add few paragraphs more.

Comment: The warning disappears if I add `\centering` just after the opening brace: `\begin{floatingtable}[r]{\centering...`

Comment: Egreg, you are right. Thanks! However, I still don't understand what LaTeX is trying to strech without `\centering`.

Comment: surely this is to be expected?  the paragraph contains a short line of text (nowhere near width of the page), and the table is minute too.  embedding the table in such a tiny paragraph does indeed produce a very empty line, just as the warning says.

Comment: Wasteofspace, as I said, "It does not make any difference if I add more words to 'This is MWE.' -paragraph or add few paragraphs more."

Comment: @wasteofspace The warning is there also when the text surrounding the inserted table is long; the `Underfull \vbox` is exactly the one built by `\floatingtable`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no warning if `\centering` is issued before `\begin{tabular}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatflt,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{floatingtable}[r]{%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{tabular}}
\end{floatingtable}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]